# Invalid argument 'columnOrOptions' when running 'vscode.diff'

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am creating an VS extension which needs to show the difference between two files

vscode.diff - Opens the provided resources in the diff editor to compare their contents.

left - Left-hand side resource of the diff editor
right - Right-hand side resource of the diff editor
title - (optional) Human readable title for the diff editor
columnOrOptions - (optional) Either the column in which to open or editor options, see vscode.TextDocumentShowOptions
(returns) - no result

When i try to specify the column in the execute commands it fails and shows error
rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: Invalid argument 'columnOrOptions' when running 'vscode.diff', received: 1
c:\Users\sivakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork.js:5
stack trace: Error: Invalid argument 'columnOrOptions' when running 'vscode.diff', received: 1

Here is the code

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.diff", vscode.Uri.file(outputpath), vscode.Uri.file(oldOutputPath),"Current ----- Old", vscode.ViewColumn.Two);
```